# How to set the working directory for ConsoleControl process?

Tags: c#, console, controls

In my application I use a [ConsoleControl](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335909/Embedding-a-Console-in-a-C-Application). And it has a method `ConsoleControl.StartProcess(string fileName, string arguments)`. Whit this method I want to execute a *.bat file, but inside this file I have relative path which is broken, because if the application is started from `c:\folder1\folder2` than the control base path will be `c:\folder1\folder2` and if my file is `c:\directory1\myfile.jar` and the *.bat file is also in `c:\directory1` than the relative path will break. I think if I can set the working directory this problem will be gone, but I dont know how to set it. I tried: `-WorkingDirectory "c:\directory1"` and `WorkingDirectory="c:\directory1"`. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the current working directory for your entire application by setting [`Environment.CurrentDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.currentdirectory) before you initialize your ConsoleControl.

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory = "c:\directory1";
```